# confusing Javascript syntax error

Tags: javascript

I am testing to see which out of three numbers passed are the greatest and returning that through one function. However, I keep getting a syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement }else (third > first && third > second) {

Here is the code:

```
function getMax3(first, second, third) {
if (first > second && first > third){
  return first;
} else if (second > first && second > third) {
  return second;
}else (third > first && third > second) {
  return third;
}
}

console.log(getMax3(10, 3, 4));
console.log(getMax3(1, 6, 9));
```

Comment: You can simply use `Math.max(10, 3, 4)`.

Comment: So... what is this `else (third > first && third > second)`

Comment: Please have look: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp
**Else** never have condition.

Answer (score 6):

As others have noted, you can of course use the [Math.max function or Math.max.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) for this specific problem. But to answer your question about this specific syntax error the following solution applies.

You cannot have a condition on an `else`. You could either change the last `else` to an `else if` or simply remove the condition and let the else catch everything not cought by the first to conditions

so either:

```
function getMax3(first, second, third) {
if (first > second && first > third){
  return first;
} else if (second > first && second > third) {
  return second;
}else {
  return third;
}
}

console.log(getMax3(10, 3, 4));
console.log(getMax3(1, 6, 9));
```

or

```
function getMax3(first, second, third) {
if (first > second && first > third){
  return first;
} else if (second > first && second > third) {
  return second;
}else if(third > first && third > second) {
  return third;
}
}

console.log(getMax3(10, 3, 4));
console.log(getMax3(1, 6, 9));
```

[Read more about if...else statements on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getMax3(first, second, third) {
if (first > second && first > third){
  return first;
} else if (second > first && second > third) {
  return second;
}else  {//the else cannot have condition
  return third;
}
}

console.log(getMax3(10, 3, 4));
console.log(getMax3(1, 6, 9));
```

This is because from your coding we can see that you have included the condition in else statement. For more info check this out >> http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMax3(first, second, third) {
if(first > second && first > third){
  return first;
} else if(second > first && second > third) {
  return second;
}else if(third > first && third > second) {
  return third;
}
}

console.log(getMax3(10, 3, 4));
console.log(getMax3(1, 6, 9));
```

Here is the modified code.
Try this......

Answer (score 0):

you can put all elements in array and add this prototype to find max among as many elements you want:

```
Array.prototype.max = function () {
    return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};
```

Ex:

```
var arr = [4,5,6,7,73,53,123,53];
var maxVal = arr.max();
```